# How to open file for random access in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I need to open a file in libgdx for random access, i.e. I need to be able to `seek()` to different parts of the file (not read sequentially).

Using libgdx I am able to access the file via `Gdx.files.internal()`, but libgdx's filehandlers don't support random access methods like `seek()`. I tried using `java.io.RandomAccessFile`, but it generates the exception `No such file or directory`, probably because the file is stored internally in the jar file.

How can I access the file using java.io.RandomAccessFile` or alternatively how  can i open file for random-access in libgdx?

This needs to work on both Android and desktop platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Libgdx limitation.  You cannot do random access on files stored inside a JAR file (since they're compressed, you need to stream the contents).  (I can't find a concise reference for this, but look at the definitions of `JarFile` and `ZipFile`: they only let you create streaming file handles).

Libgdx itself runs into this problem.  It stores native libraries in a .jar file (the `libgdx-natives.jar`).  To use the files, it extracts them to the local filesystem and uses them from there.  See [SharedLibraryLoader.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/SharedLibraryLoader.java#L139).

As far as I can tell there are three workarounds to chose from:

1. Remove the need for the random access in your code.
2. Stream the file from the JAR into memory, and randomly access it there
3. Copy the file from the JAR into `local` (private) storage or temp storage (hopefully this could be done once and not re-done on each run of the app).

Comment: So, would you suggest that the ideal course of action be that I write the file from internal() to local() and then use  RandomAccessFile on the local() file? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Yep, as far as I know, you will either need to remove the need for random access from the file, stream it all into memory, or copy it into a `local` file and use it from there.

Comment: I edited your answer to include your comments. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Ok, my edit got rejected for some reason, [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3589583)

Comment: @nedR Thanks for trying to improve my answer.  I think you're right the content belongs in the answer.  (I think the reviewers have a bit of knee-jerk reaction to questioners editing answers -- they're often done by folks that don't understand the commenting system.)  I'll update my answer.  :)